# Why do so many Android apps use the NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've been looking through a few of the apps today (was actually looking to see how many use ACRA) but noticed that a lot of them use the NDK. I've been developing apps for quite some time and have yet to find a need for the NDK and as per the [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) you shouldn't really use it unless you need to:

> In general, you should only use the NDK if it is essential to your app—never because you simply prefer to program in C/C++.

So this has got me to thinking... Am I missing something? I mean here are just a few of the apps using the NDK where I can't really see a need for it:

- WhatsApp
- TuneIn Radio Pro
- textPlus
- Microsoft Tag
- Star Chart
- SPYMouse
- SoundHound
- Roll in the Hole
- Facebook
- Skype (Likely crypto libs)
- Raging Thunder
- QR Droid
- PocketCloud
- Camera Zoom FX
- Blow Up
- Paper Camera
- Ocean HD Screen Saver
- Office Suite
- Instagram
- Jump Desktop
- Fieldrunners
- Angry Birds apps

I guess my thinking is perhaps they are using the same code on other platforms, libraries written in C and used on iOS, Android & other platforms, but I'm just not convinced that this is the reason. Are there any other things that these apps are likely to be using the NDK for? Other things I guess could be: Licensing, privacy/security (move complicated reverse engineering), Device IDs, Gaming engines etc.

Anyhow, the question is really, do you have any ideas as to why so many apps are using the NDK?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. Rather than asking why *others* want to use the NDK, ask why *you* would want to use the NDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare Actually, I don't have a reason to use it, but being an inquisitive type, I'm interested to know what and why others are doing the things they do with a view to make my stuff better. In actual fact, you're probably right, this is mostly going to be subjective and opinionated answers and probably SO isn't the place for this. Might be better for me to close it off before I get too many down votes :)

Comment: Your inquisitiveness is fine, but your particular question just isn't a great fit for the SO structure. Sorry!

Comment: @CommonsWare agreed, I have added my vote to close it.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if this question is proper for StackOveflow, but as a developer using NDK I can give you two reasons from my perspective:

- very large code base in C++, which is used also for versions on iPhones and Winrt, and also Windows CE/Desktop. It was developer for years, fixed, tested by lots of users.
- its harder for hackers to learn what your code is doing, and to break it. But not impossible.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the first reason listed by marcin is the main reason.

For my case, since there has been several C++ libraries used by IPhone and they do not want to port them to java impl, so just keep using it in Android.

Because I am a Android developer, I totally disagree with this way. From the official doc, as you emphasized:

> In general, you should only use the NDK if it is essential 
>       to your app—never because you     simply prefer to program in C/C++.

But, just hard to push the whole solution to java... Painful in debugging, trouble shooting, anything is out of control.